# Algorithms for finding covering spaces of a given space

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Taking the example of $X=S^1\vee S^1$ , to find the covering space $X$ what was done in Munkres is that we had the idea of how the real line wraps around the circle. Using this we attached circles tangentially to the integer points of the real line. Similarly we construct the covering space for the other circle. So the space we end up having is just the $x-y$ plane with circles been attached to all the integer points on both the $x$ and the $y$ axis.

Since I am new to algebraic topology all the spaces whose covering spaces I have seen invoke the same idea. We consider chunks of the actual space and see how a covering space might satisfy that chunk and then try expanding the covering space for the whole space. But this idea seems very informal as I was told this idea will not work for a surface of genus $g$.

**Question:** So as the title says what are the algorithms for finding covering spaces of a space $X$. I was told that there are algorithms hence this question.

Comment: The classification of (connected) covers of a (reasonable) path-connected space is that they correspond to conjugacy classes of subgroups of the fundamental group. This should be in any textbook that discusses covering spaces. In general it's pretty hard to describe the subgroups of some group, though, so I don't know what you're hoping for as far as an algorithmic answer.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the comment. Basically what my question is that if in general a space $X$ has been given to me how do I find a suitable covering space for it. So as you say I guess I have to look for subgroups of the fundamental group. What if we are given a space and we have to look for the universal covers for it. Does that make it more difficult?